# Conditionally redirect bash output, only print to cout and cerr on error

Tags: bash, pipe, stdout, travis-ci, stderr

Is there a simple single line way, or simple function such that a bash command:

1. Pipes cout and cerr to a file by default on success

   - In other words, do not print to the terminal on success.
2. If an error occurs (i.e. nonzero return)

   - capture the error code
   - print the file from (1)
   - return the error code
3. Bonus: would love if I can re-enable printing by default with 1 or 2 characters

Motivation: travis-ci has a 4MB limit to the total log cout/cerr size. This kills the build when it is exceeded, so I'd like to only print actual errors, but travis also terminates when an error is detected, much like `set -e`.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you need is someting like:

```
ls real_file.txt > /tmp/out.txt 2>&1 || echo $? && cat /tmp/out.txt
ls non_existent.txt > /tmp/out.txt 2>&1 || echo $? && cat /tmp/out.txt
```

Addition: after OP's feedback:

```
ls real_file.txt > /tmp/out.txt 2>&1 || (echo $? && cat /tmp/out.txt)
ls non_existent.txt > /tmp/out.txt 2>&1 || (echo $? && cat /tmp/out.txt)
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work, it shouldn't print anything on success:
    `○ echo "real_file_text" > real_file.txt`
    `○ cat real_file.txt > /tmp/out.txt 2>&1 || echo $? && cat /tmp/out.txt`
output:
    `real_file_text`

Comment: Now I understanded better. Then this should do the trick: ls real_file.txt > /tmp/out.txt 2>&1 || (echo $? && cat /tmp/out.txt)

Answer (score 1):

As descibed in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/106, you can apply global redirection for all the commands.

So you can start your script like this:

```
exec 3>&1 >log 2>&1
```

With this command , new fd 3 will be assigned to screen , existed fd1 will be sent to log file and stderr will also be sent to log file.

Give it a try (or check my test [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMclRjeFllelVRYm8))

```
exec 3>&1 >log 2>&1
ls nofile #This will raise an error on stderr
echo "hello" #This would normally be printed on stdout / fd1
echo "hello again" >&3 #This will go in fd3
#Output:
hello again

$ cat log
ls: cannot access nofile: No such file or directory                                                                                                                             
hello
```

The ls will fail (unless you have a file named "nofile" :)) but the error message will be sent to log gile.

The echo will succeed to print "hello" , but this will go to fd1 , meaning again to log file.

Last echo is redirected to fd3 = your real screen , and this is the only message you will see in reality.

One step forward, you can capture each commands result using $? (or using bash PIPESTATUS array if you are going to use pipes).

Another test :

```
exec 3>&1 >log 2>&1
ls nofile; ex=$?; 
[[ "$ex" -ne 0 ]] && (echo "Oops, something gone wrong.Exit status = $ex" && cat log) >&3 

#Output
Oops, something gone wrong.Exit status = 2
ls: cannot access nofile: No such file or directory
```

Alternative way

```
if ! ls nofile;then echo "something is wrong" >&3;fi
```

If ls fails , will print "something is wrong" on your screen
if ls does not fail will print it's results to log and you see nothing in your screen.

As a general idea, with such a method, you can have always stderr and stdout redirected to a file, and you can selectivelly print messages on the screen by applying `>&3` in each command you want it's results to be printed on your screen.

I don't know if it is possible to have automatic redirection based on exit status of each command. This is what is the use of stderr. To print errors.

It seems that you need to monitor the exit status of each command after it's execution.

Also, notice that some commands may return exit status different than zero based on the operation performed (i.e command diff)